# Progress bar in an expanded layout notification

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar

I'm trying to use a `ProgressBar` in my custom expanded layout and I only succeed in getting an indeterminate one. In my layout, the `ProgressBar` is declared in this way :

```
<ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:id="@+id/MyProgressBar"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="0"/>
```

and in my code, I use `notificationView.setProgressBar(R.id.MyProgressBar,100,0,false)` to declare it to my `RemoteViews`. I say that the `ProgressBar` must not be indeterminate twice, but it is useless...

What am I doing wrong and what should I do to correct the problem?